# Can I Change the value of a textbox with Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xhtml

I just started in Ajax today and the tutorial i was reading showed me how to use the result to change a div. But is it possible that i can get the result and make it the new value of a text box. This way i can still edit the text box but the current value will be the ajax result.

Right now i am changing the div with this line:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type='text' id='mytextbox' />

<script>
// ...
document.getElementById("mytextbox").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
// ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

document.getElementById("txtHint").**value** =xmlhttp.responseText;